# Find Text Duplicates in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm an Excel/VBA newbie and I have a question.
Is it possible to tag partial string matches between two columns in Excel?

Let's say I have two columns, A and B, that have text values in them. I want to identify rows where the A cell and B cell has a partial match.

Here are some hypothetical cases of the 'partial matches' that I'm looking for.

**Case 1: exact phrase match (Fictional Company Ltd) but one column has extra text**

Cell A2: 123456789 Fictional Company Ltd

Cell B2: Fictional Company Ltd

**Case 2: exact phrase match (Fictional Company Ltd) but both columns have extra text**

Cell A3: 123456789 Fictional Company Ltd

Cell B3: Fictional Company Ltd, 1 Main Street, City, State 12345

**Case 3: partial match**

Cell A4: Fictional Ltd

Cell B4: Fictional Company Ltd

**Case 4: word match**

Cell A5: Fictional Company Ltd

Cell B5: Fictional

I would like to identify all of those cases above. However, I don't mind running >1 set of codes to cover them all.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

**Update:** when I first created the cases, I didn't realize that I put the first word in column B as the matching word with column A. It is not the case - sometimes it is the 3rd word in column B and the 5th word in column A that matches.. the data is all over the place!

*Update 2:** also want to clarify that the cases are reversible - for example, there are some rows where it's Case 1 but cell B has more info instead of cell A.

Comment: So you always want to check *if the first word in Column B exists in the adjacent cell in Column A?* If that's correct, it's simple enough, and doesn't even need VBA...

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg thanks for your response! I did not realize that I always made examples where the potential match is always the first word in Column B. It is not always the case, sometimes it is reversed (for example, the second word in column B matches first word in column A). I will also amend the post to reflect this.

Comment: So you only need to know *if the first **or** second word in Column B exists in the adjacent cell in Column A?* Easy

Comment: I wish it's just first or second, but the data is all over the place - sometimes it is the 3rd word in column B and the 5th word in column A that matches..

Comment: ok - but always an *entire word?* (ie., word = text separate by spaces) if so, simple enough

Comment: ...how about if any one word in column A matches any one word in column B?

Comment: yes it is always an entire word separated by spaces! and yes, one word in A matches any word in B is ok!

Comment: how's that look?  If, for example, it's specifically a True/False that you need that's a quick change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns the number of times a word in `Txt1` is contained *anywhere* (not just as a word) in `Txt2`:

```
Function CountMatches(text1 As String, text2 As String) As Long
    Dim arr, x As Long
    arr = Split(text2)
    For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If text1 Like "*" & arr(x) & "*" Then CountMatches = CountMatches + 1
    Next x
End Function
```

...and this one does the same, but *also* counts each occurence of `Txt2` anywhere within `Txt1`:

```
Function CountMatches2(text1 As String, text2 As String) As Long
    Dim arr, x As Long
    arr = Split(text1)
    For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If text2 Like "*" & arr(x) & "*" Then CountMatches2 = CountMatches2 + 1
    Next x
    arr = Split(text2)
    For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If text1 Like "*" & arr(x) & "*" Then CountMatches2 = CountMatches2 + 1
    Next x
End Function
```

Both are susceptible to counting the same match twice, especially (obviously) the `CountMatches2`.

### Sample Output:

[image: img]

I'm curious if this suits your needs (as it's obviously not a true "fuzzy match")...

It can be easily modified to return a `TRUE`/`FALSE` (ie., `TRUE` = One or more matches) or to look *only* for entire word matches as opposed to "anywhere".

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg, I already tested this script and the custom function works perfectly! It is exactly what I need. Thanks so much for helping out! You just saved me from putting in >50 work hours (if not more!) instead of running this script in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 is possible, simply by truncating the length of the longer so that it matches the length of the shorter, and then seeing if they are the same. Use the LEFT function to trim the longer word to the length of the shorter one. (Use the LEN function on the shorter word to work out how long it is).

Case 2 is tricky but possible, because you effectively need to search the longer string for every possible combination of ordered words from the shorter. It's kind of a 'slightly simpler' version of Case 3.

Case 3 is damn tricky: it's pretty much a Fuzzy Match which is computationally expensive, and requires something called tokenisation to do efficiently. Microsoft has a free [Fuzzy Match addin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=15011) but it's kinda sucky...it returns many false positives to the point that you need to eyeball each and every result to make sure it is a valid one. Which completely defeats the purpose. I'm working on putting together a commercial offering in that space myself that returns far fewer false positives, but can't share code. Suffice to say that this is a very difficult thing to do efficiently.

Case 4 is trivial: you just use the SEARCH formula.

Add a whole 'nother layer of trickyness if you have multiple words in each list.

The above answer is enough to point you in the right direction for a Google search. Note that you can simplify things by substituting out things like "Ltd" and "Limited" and other sundry terms using the SUBSTITUTE formula, but you've still got a heck of a challenge on your hands.

Comment: Hi @jefferyweir thanks for your answer!
I get your explanation for Case 1 & 2. However, if the length of matching phrases are different for each row, it means I have to vary the length of characters to be truncated, right?
Yeah for case 3 it is quite complicated.
For Case 4, would you please elaborate more on that?

Typically it's just one word that matches on both columns.

Comment: Correct, you have to vary. You really need to provide a better screenshot showing some realistic sample data and associated layout, to help us formulate possible approaches.

Comment: @jeffreyweir - Speaking of fuzzy matches - have you seen [Allen Browne's **`SoundEx for VBA`**](http://allenbrowne.com/vba-Soundex.html)? :)

Comment: @ashleedawg I haven't really looked into SoundEx. I'm using Levenshtein Differencing, and also doing a whole lot of optimisation stuff incuding feeding in 'alias' dictionaries that map equivalent words or names to each other, such as Jeffrey = Jeffery = Geoffrey = Geoffery = Jeff = Geoff. Works a treat on names and I've been using it in some cool production environments but still need to wrap a UI around it for general consumption.